# Cross sections of semialgebric sets

Tags: algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

Let $n$ be bigger than two, and let $A$ be a subset of the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space.

Suppose that the intersection of $A$ with any $(n-1)$-dimensional affine hyperplane is semialgebraic.

> Can one conclude that $A$ is semialgebraic?

Comment: In the plane, any convex set that is not semialgebraic will be a counterexample. For example, consider the set which is an intersection of infinitely many hyperplanes, such that no finite subset of hyperplanes defines the set. This is convex, but probably not semialgebraic; I'm not sure how to formally prove the latter, though. Maybe you know?

Comment: Actually already for $n=1$ there are plenty of counterexamples, since *any* subset of the real line has semialgebraic sections ;)

Comment: Consider the curve (t,t^2,t^3) and pick some countable infinite set on this curve, this is a counterexample. A plane contains at most two of the points and the resulting set is in fact algebraic. But the original set is not semialgebraic.

Comment: @Patrik: you probably mean that any plane contains at most three of the points? (Every three points are contained in some plane, so your statement can't be quite right.)

Comment: Yes thats what I meant :)

Comment: an interesting question would be to assume as well that every section is also closed and without isolated points (or even convex)

Comment: Isn't the subset of the plane defined by $y > e^x$ an obvious counterexample?